# Why does Plot[D[x,x],{x,1,10}] throw error?

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, warning-messages

I am experiencing unexpected behavior from `Plot` and `D`, and I would like to understand why.  If I try this:

> Plot[D[x,x],{x,1,10}]

I get a `General::ivar` error, but if I do this:

> f = D[x,x]
>
> Plot[f,{x,1,10}]

it works just fine.  I come from a Python/Julia background, so I find this behavior baffling.  What is going on here?

Comment: Plot holds its arguments and evaluates them once numerical values have been substituted for the variable, so you end up evaluating `D[some number, some number]`, which of course does not make sense. You need to force pre-evaluation of `D`, which is exactly what you achieve when you define `f`. You would obtain the same result with `Plot[Evaluate@D[x, x], {x, 1, 10}]`. Take a look at [Evaluation of Expressions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EvaluationOfExpressions.html) and in particular the part about non-standard evaluation.

Comment: Also, please note that `D` is a built-in function so you should probably choose another name.

Comment: @anderstood Yes, I was using D as the built-in derivative function.  The example I gave of differentiating $x$ is just to illustrate the problem.

Comment: @MarcoB Thanks, that answers my question.  I would accept that as an answer if you are interested in writing it as one.

Comment: I added the message name so that if you search, say, for "[ivar Plotting](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=ivar+Plotting)", you would find an answer to your question.